# Do the 'evil' equalities slow down code?

Tags: javascript, performance, operators, equality

For my new JavaScript library, I have a function `isBinary` which returns `true` if the passed value is `1`, `0`, `true`, or `false`. I use the following code for easy writing, but I was wondering if I was slowing down the processing, and milliseconds *do* matter, because the function is parsed up to 10 thousand times in certain places. Code:

```
isBinary = function(ins) {
    return ins == 0 || ins == 1; //returns true if ins is true, false, 0, or 1      
};
```

But I wasn't exactly sure if the operator equal or `==` would be faster or slower than strictly equal, with more `||`'s.
Question for maximum clarity:
Would it be faster to use `ins === 1 || ins === 0 || ins === true || ins === false`, or `ins == 1 || ins == 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strict equality `===` will be faster.  If you use `==`, the JavaScript interpreter has to attempt to coerce the type into something that makes sense.

I do want to note, though, that your function isn't truly checking if the value passed in is `0`, `1`, `false`, or `true`.

For example:

```
function isBinary(ins) {
    return ins == 0 || ins ==1;
}

var arrayOne = [1];
var arrayOneString = ['1'];

console.log(isBinary(arrayOne)); //returns true
console.log(isBinary(arrayOneString)); //returns true
console.log(isBinary("1")); //returns true
```

I'm just demonstrating that your code isn't doing exactly what you think it's doing.  Type safety in JavaScript is difficult, and operators that aren't "strictly equal" can't be counted on to test type.

Comment: So either way, the `===` with or operators would work better for this?

Comment: Yes, strict equality would be the way to go.  It's both faster and won't give you false positives with other types due to interpreter type-coercion.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a jsPerf I conducted shortly after asking this, the longer to write version seems to be *much* faster. The prep code was:

```
<script>
function isBinaryShort(ins) {
    return ins == 1 || ins == 0;
}

function isBinaryLong(ins) {
    return ins === 1 || ins === 0 || ins === true || ins === false;
}
</script>
```

Then for both tests I used:

```
isBinaryLong(1)
isBinaryLong(false)
isBinaryLong("tree")
```

but of course, short for the shorter to write version.
And these screenshots do the talking for me.
[image]
[Link](http://jsperf.com/equalitytests) if you want to test yourself.